# Re-use the event listener created by the same React hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React hook which attaches a resize listener to the window object to measure the size of a browser width. This works great, but every new instance of a hook is created, it creates a new listener to run. I know React may use a single event listener, and re-uses it but the the number of times the browser width is measured still increases linearly by the number of hook instances created. Is there a nice way to re-use the same window resize listener for all instances of the same hook, so the measuring is only done once? I don't want to create a Context, and put it at the root since that would re-render a lot of unrelated components.

For example, I could have something like this:

```
const useMeasureBrowserWidth = () => {
 const [width, setWidth] = React.useState();
 React.useEffect(() => {
  const resizeListener = () => { setWidth(window.innerWidth); };
  window.addEventListener("resize", resizeListener);

  return () => {
   window.removeEventListener("resize", resizeListener);
  };
 }, []);

 return width;
};
```

Then, every time I use the hook in different components. it's going to perform the `setWidth(window.innerWidth)` for each instance. This sounds like a waste especially when accessing `window.innerWidth` property disrupts the rendering flow. Or, does React already do any optimizations for this scenario?

Comment: One solution I can think of is to create a Context at the root, and attach a window listener there, and save the width into a local ref variable. Then, the context can pass down a function that retrieves the value, so child components can query this on demand. But, this still attaches a root Context so it's not the nicest solution...

Comment: You can use this with useRef for targeting specific element @CookieMonster

Comment: Context is a right solution, also if you implement context correctly not all components will re-render but only those who are listening to context

Comment: Thanks, perhaps that's the easiest solution. I'll keep the question open in case someone has a different answer.